# Import CSV file with spaces in header using read_csv from readr

Tags: r, readr

I am starting to use `readr` to import CSV files with `read_csv`...how do I deal with CSV files containing spaces in the header names?

`read_csv` imports them with the spaces (and special characters) which prevents me from going straight to `mutate` and other `dplyr` functions.

How do I handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `make.names` after you read in the data.

```
df <- data.frame(x=NA)
colnames(df) <- c("This col name has spaces")
colnames(df) <- make.names(colnames(df), unique=TRUE)
```

It will return column names with periods rather than spaces as separators.

```
colnames(df)
[1] "This.col.name.has.spaces"
```

According to the help page `make.names` takes a character vector and returns a:

> A syntactically valid name consisting of letters, numbers and the dot or
>   underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed
>   by a number

EDIT: Including an example with special characters.

```
df <- data.frame(x=NA)
colnames(df) <- c("Higher than 80(°F)")
colnames(df) <- make.names(colnames(df), unique=TRUE)

colnames(df)
[1] "Higher.than.80..F."
```

As you can see `make.names` takes 'illegal' characters and replaces them with periods, to prevent any syntax errors/issues when calling an object name directly.

If you want to remove repeating `.`'s then add-

```
colnames(df) <- gsub('(\\.)\\1+', '\\1', colnames(df))
colnames(df)
[1] "Higher.than.80.F."
```

Comment: Do you know if this method will work on special characters? For example, when importing weather data `read_csv` imports the degree symbol which may cause it to error (I haven't tried yet but will update once I have!)...

Comment: That answered my original question and taught me a new function, thanks! As an aside, when importing a CSV file with `read_csv` with a header containing a degree symbol I get "Temperature..U.00B0.F" whereas `read.csv` returns "Temperature..F"

Comment: Looks like its the unicode character for [degree](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm).

Answer (score 2):

When I import a csv containing spaces in the headers I can actually access them as usual with the dollar operator. Lets say I have a data.frame (df) like this:

```
   a a b b
 1   1   1
 2   1   2
```

Where "a a" ist the name of the first column and "b b" the name of the second, I can get the first column with

```
df$`a a`
```

But if you want to change them anyways you can just rename them like this:

```
names(df) <- c("a_a", "b_b")
```

The vector you're assigning just needs to have the same length as the columns of the data.frame. A slightly more elegant way would be the use of the stringr package. If you want to replace all spaces with underscores just type this:

```
library(stringr)    
names(df) <- str_replace_all(names(df), " ", "_")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `janitor::clean_names()` function. It provides a variety of ways to transform column names without spaces. The default is `snake_case`.